# How to deal with parallel arrays in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 separate arrays (coming from Json, but that's not important). They are lined up... i.e. arr1[1] goes with arr2[1].

I want to create a list of Test objects with a few catches:

```
1) both arr1 and arr2 value can't be null
2) I'm only interested in indexes where the arr1 element is a multiple of 5
```

This is what I have so far:

```
class Test
{
    public double d1;
    public double d2;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] arr1 = new string[] { "0", "2", "5", "7", "10", "11", null, "13", "15" };
        string[] arr2 = new string[] { "11", "13", "56", "8", null, "44", "55", "66", "77" };

        var v = arr1.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Select(x => Double.Parse(x)).Where(x => (x % 5) == 0).Select((x, y) => new Test
        {
            d1 = x,
            d2 = Double.Parse(arr2[y])
        });
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to skip the ones where arr2 is null though and the alignment is getting messed up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order not to mess up alignment, you should first `.Zip` the two arrays.  Then, if I understand correctly, those indices that have `null` as value in either array should be skipped, so you filter those out with `.Where`, then do the rest of your logic.

```
class Test
{
    public double d1;
    public double d2;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] arr1 = new string[] { "0", "2", "5", "7", "10", "11", null, "13", "15" };
        string[] arr2 = new string[] { "11", "13", "56", "8", null, "44", "55", "66", "77" };

        var v = arr1
            .Zip(arr2, (x, y) => new {x, y})
            .Where(a => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.x) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.y))
            .Select(a => new Test { d1 = double.Parse(a.x), d2 = double.Parse(a.y) })
            .Where(a => (a.d1 % 5) == 0);

       // TODO, ready to enumerate over v.
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot compile this code, in vs2017, .net 4.5, did i miss anything?

Comment: @LeiYang, I fat-fingered one of the `=>` lambdas.  This should build now.  If not, try converting `string[]` to `List<string>` as I sometimes have troubles getting `IEnumerable<T>` from an array, and don't have compiler handy at the moment.

Comment: better now, but still missing one } at the end of the line starting with `Select`

Answer (score 0):

You can filter by where condition as below.

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] arr1 = new string[] { "0", "2", "5", "7", "10", "11", null, "13", "15" };
            string[] arr2 = new string[] { "11", "13", "56", "8", null, "44", "55", "66", "77" };

          var v = arr1
                   .Zip(arr2, (x, y) => new { x, y })
                   .Where(a => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.x) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.y))
                   .Select(a => new Test { d1 = double.Parse(a.x), d2 = double.Parse(a.y) })
                   .Where(a => (a.d1 % 5) == 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, this won't work as the array alignment will be messed up. arr1 nulls and not necessarily at the same index where arr2 nulls are and vice versa. LB2's answer worked though.

Comment: I have updated the code and it was throwing syntax error.